# Python- Can't overwrite first column of .csv file with new time stamp

Tags: python, csv, datetime, writer

I have a .csv file (see image):
[image]

In the image there is a time column with datetime strings, I have a program that takes this column and only reads the times H:M:S. Yet, not only in my program I am attempting to take the column to read only the time stamp H:M:S , but I am also attempting to overwrite the time column of the first file and replace it with only the H:M:S time stamp onto a the new .csv with the following code.

CODE:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import os

File = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858.csv'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(File)
output = root + '-new.csv'
with open(File,'r') as csvinput,open(output, 'w') as csvoutput:

    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        row.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time())
        all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[0])
        all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)
```

The program works, and takes the datetime strings and overwrites the string with the time stamp H:M:S in a new .csv file. However, here is the problem, the output file instead of replacing the time column it replaced every column obtaining an output file that looks like this. See 2nd image:

[image]

At this point I don' t really know how to make the new output file to look like the file of the first image, with the format H:M:S in the first column ONLY, not all scrambled like in the second image. Any suggestions?

SCREENSHOT[image] FOR BAH:

See the K column, it should be column A of the first image, and columns B,C,D,E,F,G,I,and J should stay the same like in image 1.

Download LInk of .csv file: http://www.speedyshare.com/z2jwq/HiSAM1-data-160215-164858.csv

Comment: First of all, it looks like you don't need your second for loop. In your first for loop, you are appending to row, which is defined as the first row of the reader.

Comment: @Bah I have change the Line[0] to Line[1] and what is does is that it no longer reads the time column which is the first column, but the 0.3/L column which is the second column. So I can't change the line[0] to a different value. Maybe I am not understanding what you are saying...

Comment: try commenting out your second loop completely, and changing your first loop's body (from row.append...; all.append) to this line: `all.append(line+[dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time()])` (grab latest edit, I forgot the brackets earlier)

Comment: @bah so that fixed the time stamp problem where now I have all the times in one column but everyother row still scrambled up and not looking like image 1 from the post...I don;t know what to do next.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing now and what you would like to see (just edit the csv in excel the way you'd like it to be displayed). Sorry I'm on the phone without an environment to test out the script myself.

Comment: @Bah I have updated the post with an image.

Comment: Okay to solve the issue with the columns replace what I suggested in the comment above with `all.append([dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time()]+line[1:])` Could you also `print all` before writing, after the loop.

Comment: How about posting the .csv instead of screenshots?  Much easer to cut and paste your data to help.

Comment: @marktolonen I have posted a link in the post

Comment: @bah here is the link of the new file i got with change the all.append line to all.append([dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time()]+line[1:]). See link: http://www.speedyshare.com/n5sHy/HiSAM1-data-160215-164858-new.csv  It did put the time in the first column but is in between scrabled columns. Please see link.

Comment: Links can go bad.  Just edit your question and add a few lines of sample data.

Comment: @marktolonen nevermind, albertoql was able to point out my mistake. Thanks for the help though :) you rock too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code seems that you're keeping appending to the first row the time of each of the line in the csv, which results in the second image posted in the question.

The idea is to keep track of the different lines and modify just the first element of each line. Also, if you want, you should keep the first line, which indicates the labels of the column. For solving the issue, the code would look like:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import os

File = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858.csv'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(File)
output = root + '-new.csv'
with open(File,'r') as csvinput,open(output, 'w') as csvoutput:

    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    rows = [next(reader)]
    for line in reader:
        line[0] = str(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time())
        rows.append(line)

    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Note the list `rows` has the modified lines from the `csvinput`.

The resulting output csv file (tested with the first line in the question duplicated) would be
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With some simplified data:

```
#!python3
import csv
import datetime as dt
import os

File = 'data.csv'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(File)
output = root + '-new.csv'

# csv module documents opening with `newline=''` mode in Python 3.
with open(File,'r',newline='') as csvinput,open(output, 'w',newline='') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    # Copy the header
    row = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(row)

    # Edit the first column of each row.
    for row in reader:
        row[0] = dt.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').time()
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Input:

```
Time,0.3(/L),0.5(/L)
02/15/2016 13:44:01,88452,16563
02/15/2016 13:44:02,88296,16282
```

Output:

```
Time,0.3(/L),0.5(/L)
13:44:01,88452,16563
13:44:02,88296,16282
```

If actually on Python 2, the `csv` module documents using binary mode.  Replace the `with` line with:

```
with open(File,'rb') as csvinput,open(output, 'wb') as csvoutput:
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite a single row in the CSV file. You'll have to write all the rows you want to a new file and then rename it back to the original file name.

Your pattern of usage may fit a database better than a CSV file. Look into the sqlite3 module for a lightweight database.